PHP mix socket and class to open and close an IMAP connection
I'm using the php-imap library from Barbushin (https://github.com/barbushin/php-imap) to connect to mailboxes via pop3 and imap. When I try to delete a mail using the POP3 protocol, it doesn't work. It turns out it's an issue with the IMAP extension that doesn't send the Close command when disconnecting (https://github.com/Eden-PHP/Mail/issues/1#issuecomment-375120604). I would like connect to the server using the library but then disconnect from the server using a socket, in order to send the  "close" command and solve the issue. Can I somehow pickup the connection from the php-imap class and use it to send a socket command?
Thank you!
